# Допустимо ли существенно дописывать чужой ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Вот решил кто-то вдруг [дописать кучу текста](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/625869/revisions) в третьей ревизии. На мой взгляд, это стоило постить отдельным ответом. Но откатывать уже сделанную правку нехорошо, т. к. она всё же полезна. Сейчас оставлю комментарий автору, ещё есть вариант запостить дополнения отдельным общим ответом самому.

Допустимы ли такие правки и как с ними поступать?

Comment: [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474/137096)

Comment: [Does this edit change the meaning of the answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338490/4279)

Comment: А я вот просто не понимаю, что двигало правившим, по сути сделавшим  ваши 3 строки  полноценным ответом. За 1.5 часа до  его правок (и через 4 минуты после вашего ответа) уже был дан по сути тоже полноценный ответ и тоже с большим количеством букв. / Наерное стоит считать данный случай уникальным.

Comment: @avp, вроде он даже принят был на момент правки :)

Answer (score 8):

#### Что хорошо

Ответ из пары строк кода не объясняет суть проблемы.
Неявное приведение типов — довольно простой, но важный аспект языка.
Дополненный ответ хоть как-то о нём рассказывает.

#### Что плохо

В дополнении ужасный (с моей точки зрения) стиль:

- Проблемы с терминологией:

  - Противопоставляются непохожие термины "целочисленное значение" и "дробное число".
  - Термин "неявное преобразование типов" не вводится, но сразу используется. Нельзя так с терминами.
- Объекты одного типа выглядят в тексте по-разному, а должны одинаково:

  - Термины выделяются то курсивом, то полужирным начертанием.
  - Код внутри цитаты стал просто цитатой.
  - Внутристрочный код `java` — на самом деле не код.
- Неуместное "Как вы помните,". Так можно было бы говорить, если бы в прошлом абзаце или главе уже обсуждалось целочисленное деление.

Ну и с точки зрения правил SO:

- Пример кода должен быть в ответе, ссылка на ideone может его только дополнять.
- Стоило бы посоветоваться с автором, добавляя гораздо больше текста, чем уже было.

#### Результат

Как мне кажется, получившийся в итоге ответ немного раскрывает проблему, но при этом запутывает читателя. Полной информации о том, как работает приведение типов с числами, в нём нет. Четких и понятных определений тоже нет.

#### Вывод

Думаю, что вы вольны полностью откатить дополнение, т.к. в нём достаточно деструктивного. Но ответ станет лучше, если вы *просто и точно* объясните, как работает приведение типов. Можете переработать текст дополнения, можете с нуля написать — как вам удобнее.

Answer (score 3):

Допустимо, если это не нарушает намерения автора.

Как определить нарушает ли это намерение автора:

1. Использовать здравый смысл—поставьте себя на место автора: является ли ваше дополнение улучшением ответа, с точки зрения автора? Если сомневаетесь (даже чуть-чуть), явно оставьте комментарий к ответу, что вы не возражаете, что правку можно откатить, если автор с ней не согласен (если вы хотите быть особенно дружелюбным)
2. Автор откатил правку.

В приведённом примере правка не является идеальной, но она явно улучшает  ответ, фактически словами описывая что код уже выражал.

Поправить существующий ответ и/или создать новый, зависит от конкретных обстоятельств—*общим критерием здесь в первую очередь является удобство/польза для будущего читателя* как вы её лично понимаете, к примеру:

- если опубликованы разные ответы, которые только в деталях отличаются, вместо одного, то это может быть плохо для читателя (*хуже отношение сигнал/шум*). Не всегда очевидно являются ли детали существенными или нет без подробного чтения ответов (даже если автор ответа был достаточно любезным, чтобы явно подчеркнуть отличия от других ответов). С другой стороны, иногда полезно одну и ту же идею выразить разными словами/с разных углов (разным людям разные объяснения могут быть более понятными)
- если ответы конкурирующие идеи выражают, то публикуя их отдельно, голосование может показать популярность разных подходов среди участников (что в среднем *полезную информацию для читателя несёт*).

К примеру, если вышла новая версия языка/библиотеки и можно дополнить  существующий ответ примером кода, объяснением/ссылкой на другой ответ, касающийся новой версии, то иногда имеет смысл это сделать вместо/в дополнение публикации нового ответа—если есть очень старый популярный ответ и новая версия лучше решение предоставляет, то так как многие люди, прочитав популярный ответ, могут покинуть страницу не увидев лучшего решения, то стоит обновить ответ.

Практика показывает, что люди могут иметь разные точки зрения даже по тривиальным вопросам, поэтому если вашу правку откатили, то не воспринимайте это лично, а просто опубликуйте свой ответ, выражающий вашу точку зрения. В этом смысле, чаще всего стоит новый ответ дать вместо дополнения старого.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я знаю, изначально СО задумывался как полностью общественное место - все редактируют всех, причем до такой степени, что если тебя отредактировали определенное количество раз, то ответ у тебя отбирается и переходит в собственность сообщества.

Со временем власти предержащие сообразили, что такой коммунизм не поощряет, мягко говоря, желание делиться знаниями, и отыграли назад. Теперь править ответ нельзя даже если он ошибочный и в корне неверный. Имеются ввиду смысловые правки - грамматику и оформление править разрешается и поощряется. Должны же ничего не знающие энтузиасты на чем-то зарабатывать первые 2 тыщи репутации.

Так что ответ - нет, недопустимо. В данном случае редактор явно ошибся, и стал редактировать вместо добавления собственного ответа.

Comment: "*Теперь править ответ нельзя даже если он ошибочный и в корне неверный.*" - зачем это делать? Просто размещайте другой, *правильный*, ответ, а тот - минусуйте.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае, я бы избегал исправлять чужие ответы без обсуждения с автором:

1. Я могу банально ошибаться или не понять до конца оригинальный ответ.
2. Ряд людей воспринимает StackOverflow не как базу знаний а скорее как площадку для публикации своей точки зрения, поэтому такую правку автор может воспринять негативно и в результате будет не готов к конструктивному обсуждению путей улучшения своего ответа.

Если ответ на хороший вопрос плох или не полон, то наиболее простой и удобный для всех способ решить проблему - опубликовать свой собственный ответ. Со временем сообщество плюсами поднимет его наверх, и хороший ответ будет легко найти.

Но все же бывают ситуации, когда стоит попытаться улучшить ответ данный ранее другим человеком путем добавления в него существенных подробностей. Допустим, если ответ в целом хорош и уже набрал определенное количество плюсов. В таком случае от двух одинаковых ответов больше пользы не будет.

К сожалению, о ситуации, когда существенную правку внесли в мой ответ, я могу рассуждать только в сослагательном наклонении, так как не имею такого опыта. Я считаю что в таком случае следует исходить из того, что человек который внес правку руководствовался целью улучшить содержание базы знаний, и не спешить ее отклонять (речь не идет о вандализме и очевидно деструктивной правке).

Если я с правкой не согласен, то прежде чем ее отклонить, стоит как минимум внимательно перечитать вопрос ТС и попробовать рассмотреть свой ответ с разных точек зрения. Вместо того, чтобы правку отклонять, ее можно дополнить или улучшить, поощряя таким образом стремление улучшать базу знаний. В идеале, хорошо бы обсудить правку с ее автором, потому что вдвоем получится учесть больше нюансов.